# How to Encrypt Request Data in Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin

There are many examples of encryption.
It's not available at the moment.

The methods have changed a lot.

All I want is to send data using Retrofit.
I'm encrypting it with AES256.
What can you do?

```
 class Encryptor: Interceptor {
            override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
                var request = chain.request()
                val body = request.body()
    //------------------------------ HOW...
                var byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
                var sink = Okio.sink(byteArrayOutputStream)
                var bufferedSink = Okio.buffer(sink)
    
                body!!.writeTo(bufferedSink)
    
                bufferedSink.close()
    
                var buffer: String = "a"
                bufferedSink.writeUtf8(buffer)
//------------------------------
    
    
    //            val buffer = Buffer()
    //
    //            body!!.writeTo(buffer)
    //            val strOldBody: String = body.   buffer.readUtf8()
    //            val mediaType: MediaType = MediaType.parse("text/plain; charset=utf-8")
    //            val strNewBody: String = encrypt(strOldBody)
    //            val body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, strNewBody)
    //            request = request.newBuilder().header("Content-Type", body.contentType().toString())
    //                .header("Content-Length", body.contentLength().toString())
    //                .method(request.method(), body).build()
                return chain.proceed(request)
            }
    
            private fun encrypt(text: String): String? {
                //your code
                return text
            }
        }
```

I know how to do AES256.
I just want to know how to encrypt the body.

Comment: Can you just use HTTPS?

Comment: Development server : http / Commercial server : https
,It should all be applied.